# My notification system is having issues with the error "attempt to call instance value"

Tags: lua, roblox

So the full code is here in the two parts: Server and Local. I am trying to make a system that stores the Balance of the user, from the table, in a IntValue inside of their player in `game.Players` then call it later to check if it has changed. If It has, send a Notification to the GUI via a local script. Whatever happens, the notification does not appear. If you need anything else, I'm happy to give you it. Thanks for reading and any potential help. This is for a game called Opix Islands on Roblox, I am not an expert nor a noob, I just got a bit stuck.

**Server:**

```
    while true do
    for i,v in game.Players do --this is the line with the error.

            local tab = nil
            for I,V in pairs(_G.GlobalData) do
                if V.UserId == v.UserId then
                    tab = V
                end
            end
            if not v.Bank then
                newval = Instance.new("IntValue",v)
                newval.Name = "Bank"
                wait()
                newval.Value = tab.Bank

            else
                if tab.Bank > v.Bank.Value then
                    print ("Greater than stored value")
                    local changedby = tab.Bank - v.Bank.Value
                    game.ReplicatedStorage.Notif.Return:FireClient(v,changedby,false)
                elseif tab.Bank < v.Bank.Value then
                    print ("Less than stored value")
                    local changedby = v.Bank.Value - tab.Bank
                    game.ReplicatedStorage.Notif.Return:FireClient(v,changedby,true)--Player to send to,amount it has changed by,If it has gone down
                end             
            end
            
        end

    wait()  
    end
```

**And the Local script:**

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.Notif.Return.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(Change,Down)
     if Down == false then
        local Notification = script.Parent.NotificationExample:Clone()
        Notification.Name = "Notification"
        Notification.Parent = script.Parent
        Notification.Text = "Your Bank account balance has just increased by: £"..Change
        print ("Bank account Increased by:"..Change)
        Notification.Visible = true
        print ("Notification should be visible")
        wait(3)
        Notification:Destroy()
        print ("Notification should be gone!")
    elseif Down == true then
            local Notification = script.Parent.NotificationExample:Clone()
            Notification.Parent = script.Parent
            Notification.Name = "Notification"
            Notification.Text = "Your Bank account balance has just decreased by: £"..Change
            print ("Bank account decreased by:"..Change)
            Notification.Visible = true
            print ("Notification should be visible")
            wait(3)
            Notification:Destroy()
            print ("Notification should be gone!")
    
    
    
    end
    
    
end)
```

**Here's a picture of the hierarchy, the event is in the replicated storage.**
[image: hierarchy]

***Many Thanks.***

Comment: well looks like you're calling an instance value somewhere. I cannot see such a call in the provided code. so maybe it happens because you provided an instance instead of a function value as a callback or so. please do your own debugging. error messages usually come with a line number btw

Comment: Its the marked line. Line 18. 
 for i,v in game.Players do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `game.Players` is not a function.

Something like this

```
for i,v game.Players do

end
```

cannot work.

From the [Lua manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.5):

> A for statement like
>
> ```
>  for var_1, ···, var_n in explist do body end works as follows.
> ```
>
> The names var_i declare loop variables local to the loop body. The
> first of these variables is the control variable.
> The loop starts by evaluating explist to produce four values: an
> iterator function, a state, an initial value for the control variable,
> and a closing value.
>
> Then, at each iteration, Lua calls the iterator function with two
> arguments: the state and the control variable.

In your case Lua will treat `game.Players` as the iterator function as this is the first (and only) element of the `explist` you provide.
When called it will result in the observed error as it is not a function value.

You probably want to do something like

```
for i,v in ipairs(game.Player:GetChildren()) do end
```

Answer (score -1):

```lua
    while true do
    for i,v in pairs(game.Players:GetChildren()) do --this is the line with the error.

            local tab = nil
            for I,V in pairs(_G.GlobalData) do
                if V.UserId == v.UserId then
                    tab = V
                end
            end
            if not v.Bank then
                newval = Instance.new("IntValue",v)
                newval.Name = "Bank"
                wait()
                newval.Value = tab.Bank

            else
                if tab.Bank > v.Bank.Value then
                    print ("Greater than stored value")
                    local changedby = tab.Bank - v.Bank.Value
                    game.ReplicatedStorage.Notif.Return:FireClient(v,changedby,false)
                elseif tab.Bank < v.Bank.Value then
                    print ("Less than stored value")
                    local changedby = v.Bank.Value - tab.Bank
                    game.ReplicatedStorage.Notif.Return:FireClient(v,changedby,true)--Player to send to,amount it has changed by,If it has gone down
                end             
            end
            
        end

    wait()  
    end
```